# Uninstalling Xcode 9.4.1 before installing Xcode 10 GM?

Tags: xcode, uninstallation, diskspace, xcode10

My disk is full, and I have tried everything to try and free it up.

Xcode 9.4.1 is taking up 5.54 GB on disk and I can't unzip Xcode 10 GM without it failing because of disk space available.

Is it safe to uninstall/delete the current Xcode app (9.4.1) and then start fresh with installing Xcode 10?

(I hope this doesn't sound really dumb, but just want to be safe than sorry)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I hope this doesn't sound really dumb

The only dumb part is that part about not having enough room on your disk. You need to fix that (though that is not a Stack Overflow topic). Space is *cheap* so get some. In your situation, if you are really that short of space and you can't find any more, I would suggest putting the *.xip* file onto an external drive, unzipping there, then copying Xcode itself onto your real disk. However, it would be better to free up the space. Use DaisyDisk to find out what's taking up the space and delete some unneeded big stuff.

The question itself, though, is perfectly reasonable, and the answer is, there's no problem at all with deleting Xcode 9.4, emptying the trash (takes quite a while), and then installing Xcode 10.

Comment: Appreciate your help Matt - never thought about giving an external drive a go! I'll also check out DaisyDisk, there's definitely something hidden eating up all the space.

Answer (score 2):

Weird as it may sound. Restarting my mac solved it for me. (After you have enough space for it)

I still have my Xcode 9.4 along with Xcode 10 GM.

Comment: This is also a good idea. Restarting mac gets you more space :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rakesha! I always find restarting my mac helps free up disk space (strange really) - i'll give it a shot!

Comment: @RyanBoyling i don't think it has anything to do with free space. I already cleared enough space for it and it still showed me that error.

Answer (score 1):

I have just done it and it is safe. If you feel insecure backup your most  apps, but I don't think it's necessary. :)

Comment: Thank you! I've backed them up on the cloud just to be sure! :-)

Comment: Yeah, so there should be no problem :)