# Installing SublimeText 4

Tags: macos, sublimetext4

this is such a beginners question but nevertheless wanted some of your input.

I tried installing SublimeText4 and noticed that there is no .dmg file associated with it, all i get .zip - is this normal? Usually with SBT3 and Pycharm I was used to at least some 'install' procedures.

Kind of new to Mac OS, so thanks for the help.

Comment: So what is inside .zip?

Comment: Basically just the SBT4 application - doesn't show up on my application folder though just on the desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DMG approach is common, but in this case, the ZIP file has the application. Often the browser will automatically unzip it for you, but if not, just double click on the ZIP file and the application will be extracted for you. Then you can just drag the app extracted from the ZIP file to your “Applications” folder and you are done.

Comment: Our duty is to vote to close, not answer. This should be migrated off this site.

Comment: @matt - IIRC, we’ve had this discussion before, so I’ll again respectfully disagree. This forum is not solely for code questions. It also is for questions about “[software tools commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)”, which this obviously is. If OP asked question about how to install Microsoft Word or something like that, I’d agree with you. But as it was a question about a programming tool, it is perfectly suitable for this forum, IMHO.

Comment: FWIW, you have [answered other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52370347/1271826) about installing development tools. You didn’t vote to close that question. This falls into the same category.

Comment: I'm not so good at it either, I know! And sometimes it's hard to tell where the lines are. But surely what a zip file is, or what do with a zipped app, is not programming related.

Comment: Like I said, I disagree. This seems like a very specific, practical, and answerable about how to install a specific developer tool that is using a somewhat atypical distribution/installation mechanism. It’s not terribly complicated installation, but just a tad unusual, especially to someone who has not encountered it before. It’s not like I went into some unrelated discussion about using third party software packages or other general computing topics…